# Text inside UI Automator does not match text on actual device

Tags: android, appium, android-uiautomator

Building Automation for our Android App using UI Automator. But after recent SDK upgrade of the app, UI changed automatically and it would be good time to run automation script to catch bugs. And it passes all test cases. But if we look on UI on actual device(button "RATE SERIES" in capital), in UI Automator("Rate Series" lower case) they don't match. In Android code it in lower case and I build TC also to check that text.Is it UI Automator issue? Any way Can I fix it?

[image]

Comment: what is your test case/scenario ? make uiautomator code from whatever info getting from uiautomatorviewer. Is the difference in `uiautomatorviewer` and actual UI affecting your test case ?

Answer (score 1):

Add to your `Button` `android:textAllCaps="false"` atribut.

Comment: I was wondering why UI Automator did no catch this issue? By your answer we have to change code around whole app. But I build automation tests to catch issues and not do it manual testing(it was whole purpose to do it)

Comment: In default `Button` `textAllCaps` set as true by default.

Comment: Where? In UI Automator? Or in android  code? Because I'm doing automation and not building app

Comment: @IlyaG you would have to make that change onto your app code

Comment: @nullpointer, my question actually was: why UI Atomatorviewer does not catch the Defect on UI side. this is why we have automation to catch UI issues. But it does not work as expected

Comment: @IlyaG : for details you must read what UIAutomatorViewer is and how does Appium make use of it.

Comment: @nullpointer : I did read on website and I though this is how it suppose to work. "The uiautomatorviewer tool provides a convenient GUI to scan and analyze the **UI components currently displayed on an Android device.** You can use this tool to inspect the layout hierarchy and view the properties of UI components that are visible on the foreground of the device."  I' m thinking may be it UI Automator bug?